# User Account credentials, and how to change Ubuntu-Budgie

Tags: users, hostname, accounts, ubuntu-budgie

I am running into a situation where I need to change the terminal 'user' in Ubuntu-Budgie, but I am not seeing how this can be accomplished yet, mainly because I am not sure of the 'name' I need to change.

My user string in the terminal is: `viatech@vt` I want it to read `vt@vt`

The **vt** was changed throughout editing `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` through gedit, how do I alter `viatech` in the overall terminal name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since viatech is your your user name, to change it to vt:

```
groupadd vt
usermod -d /home/vt -m -g vt -l vt viatech
sudo reboot
```

that's it. [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98461/proper-way-of-changing-username-in-ubuntu-or-any-linux)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding the answer a bit earlier, but the snippet is essentially the same.